# VBA set range syntax

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried variations of whatever I could find so far, but no luck. Does anyone notice an error in my syntax? I get the error "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global" failed. Here is the snippet of code I am referring to:

```
 Sub newVariable()

      Dim a As Range
      Set a = Range(".Cells(1,1), .Cells(5,1)")

 End Sub
```

Comment: `Set a = Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(5,1))`

Comment: FYI you only use the leading period `.Cells()` when you're inside a `With` block - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement