# Pasting range across workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I am trying to copy/paste a range to another workbook. I am using variables to define the cells/ranges because the destination range changes on a daily basis. This method worked for pasting cells only, but I am getting application-defined or object-defined error error now that I am trying it with range. The error is in the last two lines, and is certainly deriving from the range stored as "a". The line runs perfectly when I use hard coded ranges, but the variable is throwing it off. Here's my code: Any thoughts?

```
Sub pasteVariableRange()
      Dim x1 As Integer
      Dim x2 As Integer
      Dim y As Integer
      x1 = Sheets("Source").Cells(19, 14).value
      x2 = Sheets("Source").Cells(23, 14).value
      y = Sheets("Source").Cells(19, 15).value

      Workbooks.Open ("Book2".xlsx")
      Worksheets("Destination").Activate
        Dim a As Range
        Set a = Range(Cells(x1, y), Cells(x2, y))
      
    Application.Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheets("Destination").Range("a") _
    = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Source").Range(".Cells(19, 8), .Cells(23, 8)")
 End Sub
```

Comment: Variables don't belong inside quotes. `Application.Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheets("Destination").Range("a") ` should just be `a`.

Comment: Side note, but do you understand [Tim's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71786631/vba-set-range-syntax#comment126860847_71786631) on your previous question? Because you definitely haven't applied it to the last line.

Comment: @BigBen Great catch, I have applied that to the last line and corrected the variable reference, still facing the same error. Do you think that there is an issue with using Range(Cells()) in this case? When I try replacing the variable with hard numbers as a check it returns the same error, but when I use a reference like Range("H6:H12") for example I have no issue. I really appreciate your help on this, has been a headache all day.

Comment: Please update the code in your post to the current version you're having a problem with.  We don't see any changes you've made.

Answer (score 1):

Should be close:

```vb
Sub pasteVariableRange()
    
    Dim x1 As Long, x2 As Long, y As Long 'prefer Long over Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook, a As Range, wsSrc As Worksheet
    
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
    With wsSrc
        x1 = .Cells(19, 14).Value
        x2 = .Cells(23, 14).Value
        y = .Cells(19, 15).Value
        Set a = .Range(.Cells(x1, y), .Cells(x2, y))
    End With
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Book2.xlsx")
    wb.Worksheets("Destination").Range(a.Address) = a.Value
    wb.Close True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Application.Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheets("Destination").Range("a") _
> = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Source").Range(".Cells(19, 8), .Cells(23, 8)")
> ```

This might be easier to follow.

```
Dim src_sh as Sheet
Dim des_sh as Sheet

Set src_sh = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Source")
Set des_sh = Application.Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheets("Destination")
des_sh.Range(a) = src_sh.Range(src_sh.Cells(19, 8), src_sh.Cells(23,8))
```

Comment: Sorry, that was only for the last two lines.